# Can you explain the step in this text please?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative, tensors, tangent-spaces

[image]

I don't understand how (1.2.3) is equal to (1.2.2).  I'm happy with everything up to (1.2.2) but I don't understand the explanation and step to (1.2.3) at all.

$\bar{u}^1,\bar{u}^2$ were not defined anywhere before this section.
The Einstein summation notation is being used here.

I understand this isn't much to go on but I appreciate any alternative explanation you might be able to offer.

Comment: It seems we are changing our basis of the tangent plane from $\{X_u, X_v\}$ to $\{\bar{X_u},\bar{X_v}\}$. This is a common act in differential geometry, since the whole field is about studying properties invariant under reparametrization.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler: Actually, it's $\bar X_{\bar u^i}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is standard material when discussing surfaces (or manifolds in general), and it boils down to the chain rule.

For example, you could use standard cartesian coordinates $u^1=x$, $u^2=y$ on the plane and take the parametrization
$$X(u^1,u^2) = (u^1,u^2),$$
or you could use polar coordinates (on a large open subset of the plane) $\bar u^1=r$, $\bar u^2=\theta$, and take the parametrization
$$\bar X(\bar u^1,\bar u^2) = (u^1\cos u^2, u^1\sin u^2).$$
Then $X_1 = X_{u^1} = (1,0)$, $X_2 = X_{u^2} = (0,1)$ give the standard basis for the tangent plane at any point. Or you can use
$\bar X_1 = \bar X_{\bar u^1} = (\cos u^2, \sin u^2)$ and $\bar X_2 = \bar X_{\bar u^2} = (-u^1\sin u^2,u^1\cos u^2)$ as the polar coordinate basis (written $\hat r$, $r\hat\theta$ in physics texts).

If you take a general tangent vector, you can write it as a linear combination of each set of basis vectors. The chain rule tells you how those linear combinations are related. Say a vector is written $\sum\xi^i X_i = \sum \bar\xi^j\bar X_j$. By the standard multivariable chain rule, we have
$$\bar X_{\bar u^j} = \sum \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial \bar u^j} X_{u^i}.$$
Thus, 
$$\sum\bar\xi^j\bar X_j = \sum \bar\xi^j \bar X_{\bar u^j} = \sum \bar\xi^j \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial \bar u^j} X_{u^i}=\sum \xi^i X_{u^i},$$
which tells us that
$$\xi^i = \sum \bar\xi^j \frac{\partial u^i}{\partial \bar u^j}.$$
Inversely (here you of course use invertibility of the Jacobian),
$$\bar\xi^j = \sum \xi^i \frac{\partial\bar u^j}{\partial u^i}.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helped me come to understand it.